# Copied S3 Bucket is not public by default

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have two S3 buckets -

1. `production`
2. `staging`

I want to periodically refresh the `staging` bucket so it has all the latest `production` objects for testing, so I used the `aws-cli` as follows -

```
aws s3 sync s3://production s3://staging
```

So now both buckets have the exact same files.

However, for any given file/object, the `production` link works and the `staging` doesn't

e.g.

```
This works:   https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/production/users/photos/000/001/001/medium/my_file.jpg
This doesn't: https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/staging/users/photos/000/001/001/medium/my_file.jpg
```

The `staging` bucket's objects are not public links, and are private by default.

Is there a way to correct this or avoid this with the `aws-cli`? I know I can change the bucket policy itself, but it was previously working with all the files that were there. So I'm wondering what it is about copying files over that changed their visibility.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just did some more research.

Frédéric's answer is correct, but just wanted to expand on that a bit more.

`aws s3 sync` isn't really a true "sync" by default. It just goes through each file in the source bucket and copies files into the target bucket

- If a target file with the same name already exists. I looked for a `--force` flag to force the overwrite, but apparently none exists
- It won't delete "extra" files in the target directory by default (i.e. a file that does not exist in the source directory). The `--delete` flag will allow you to do that
- It does **not** copy over permissions by default. It's true that `--acl public-read` will set the target permissions to publicly readable, but that has 2 problems - (1) it just blindly sets that for all files, which you may not want, and (2) it doesn't work when you have several files of varying permissions.

There's an [issue about it here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/901), and a PR that's open but still un-merged as of today.

So if you're trying to do a full blind refresh like me for testing purposes, the best option is to

1. Completely empty the target `staging` bucket by right clicking in the console and clicking `Empty`
2. Run the sync and blindly set everything as `public-read` (other visibility options are available, see documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)). - `aws s3 sync s3://production s3://staging  --acl public-read`

Comment: you might want to look at [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) tool - see [this page](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd-sync) for main option with `s3cmd sync` there are options like `—delete-removed` ...

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to add `--acl` flag :

```
aws s3 sync s3://production s3://staging  --acl public-read
```

as mentioned in [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl) `private` acl is the default

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful. I added my own answer with a bit more detail as well